# Tycho Maven Offline Build

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, tycho

We are building our Eclipse RCP application using Maven/Tycho. Inside eclipse everything works as expected with

```
clean install
```

However, as our build server is a virtual machine without internet connection, this won't work. We run

```
clean install --offline
```

on it but it keeps saying:

```
The POM for org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:jar:0.25.0 is missing, no dependency information available

[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:

Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:0.25.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:jar:0.25.0, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1:
Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:jar:0.25.0 has not been downloaded from it before.
```

Is it possible to have the tycho-maven-plugin available offline? We can provide the POMs as well, if you need it for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Tycho does support `--offline` (at least since Tycho 0.25, which fixes [Bug 461787](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=461787)). The error message you quote, however, indicates that Tycho **itself** was not downloaded completely by your initial `mvn clean install`.

Check that both `org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:jar:0.25.0` and `org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1` (from the error message) are present in your local Maven repository, as Maven complains it can’t find them there. Did you clean your local repository in the meantime?

Comment: I assume the local repo is .m2/repository/ ? If so, yes it is present in there.

Comment: This is odd. Can you delete `~/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho`, then perform an **online** `mvn clean install` (should download all `org.eclipse.tycho` dependencies again) followed by an **offline** `mvn clean install`?

Comment: That didn't fix it unfortunately. Do I need to set the local repository anywhere? Or does Maven always look it up at C:/.m2/repository as default?

Comment: That’s the default. You can run `mvn help:effective-settings` to check whether something (most likely your `settings.xml`) overwrote the `<localRepository>`.